# TypeScript - How can pick off some properties from a interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

e.g. I defined a structure for posts like this:

```
interface PostsInfo{
    md_content    :string;
    id            :number;
    title         :string;
    description   :string;
    update_time   :Date;
    create_time   :Date;
    comment_count :number;
}
```

then, I need an other interface that without a property which is `md_content`.

```
interface PostsInfoWithoutContent{
    // How define?
}
```

It can fix this right now that make `PostsInfo` extend `PostsInfoWithoutContent`, but, if I do like that, how can I do when I need `PostsInfoWithoutComment` (remove `comment_count` from `PostsInfo`)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the buit-in Pick type to get part of an interface :

```
type PostsInfoWithoutConent= Pick<PostsInfo, "id" | "title">
```

If you just want to exclude one property you might be better off defining the the [Omit](http://ideasintosoftware.com/typescript-advanced-tricks/) type and use that

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];  
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>; 
type PostsInfoWithoutContent= Omit<PostsInfo, "md_content">
```

Comment: In TypeScript 2.7.1, using `type PostsInfoWithoutConent= Omit<PostsInfo, typeof "comment_count">`, TypeScript tell me `error TS1003: Identifier expected`. Removing `typeof` it wosks.

Comment: @花生PeA Sorry about that, fixed, I had a custom compiler

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following information is useful too:

If you want to get the type only of a property inside of a interface, you can use lookup types:

```js
interface Person {
  name: "Paul"|"Peter"|"Percy";
}

// (1) 'Pick' result: {name: "Paul"|"Peter"|"Percy"}
type AllowedNames = Pick<Person, "name">
// in this case you want to prefer using an interface instead

// (2) 'Lookup Types' result: "Paul"|"Peter"|"Percy"
type AllowedNames = Person["name"]
```

Example: I had to access the allowed values of `compactType` which is a key in `CoreProps` (react-grid-layout), and `CoreProps` has been exported. Took me a while to stop forcing `Pick` into it.